# How to make sections of PHP code in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, meta, comments

I've really only just discovered that you can use /** @blah */ comments to specify certain things, but is it possible to create sections in code?

Like:

```
/** Start Section "Blah" **/
$result = doSomething();
echo $result;
/** End Section "Blah" */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No PDT can't do that. Generally expandable code sections are identified by function and class method bodies.

If you think you need artificial sections identified by comments I recommend to rather think about reorganizing your code into more fine grained files, function, classes and methods that can be easily documented using [PhpDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) (which is the standard PDT uses).

Comment: This answer was outdated the moment it was placed, PHP has had `goto` sections since 2009 with the release of **PHP 5.3**.

Comment: I am wondering, what's a PDT?

Answer (score 0):

these sections

```
 /**
   * here goes your text
   * @author Nanne
   * /
```

Are based on javadoc: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Look at this page where a documenter for PHP is described. I don't know what standard is used in Eclipse, but I'm guessing they're all rather alike:
http://www.phpdoc.org/

Is is mostly based on commenting certain parts of code, e.g. classes, functions and variables. As far as I know there is no special code for "sections". The reason I think this, is that you are 'supposed' to make a documentation from this, with classes, it's methods etc. There is no special way to represent "sections" in a documentation like that.

But do read above links, it'll clear up a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use sections to separate pieces of code. Syntax is like this:

```
Blah:{
   $result = doSomething();
   echo $result;
}
```

These were used by `goto` style procedural programming before object oriented programming was used (classes and instances). Using these sections and `goto` statements is very bad practice and should be shunned by any developer.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php